# Abnormal Characters has been written into the file

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

```
private static void write(String x, File file)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(x) ;
    FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        fop.write(tokenizer.nextToken().toLowerCase().getBytes());
        fop.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
    }
}
```

Regarding to the above code, I call this function within my code to write some words when some conditions hold. However, there are times that I face some strange characters such as `â€`, `sÃ©` etc. How is it possible to prevent such things to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to store "characters" in a file you have to turn them into a sequence of bytes. You can use `getBytes()` directly as you do, or you can use stream writers to do this for you.

Unfortunately there are many different ways of representing accented characters and other characters that are outside the original ASCII set. `getBytes()` in your code returns one such representation, based on your system default encoding.

When you see the strange characters, it's not that there's something wrong with the file, it's that you're reading the file using a different encoding.

You need to know what encoding you are looking for in the output, and then you can tell `getBytes()` to produce that encoding. For example:

```
fop.write(tokenizer.nextToken().toLowerCase().getBytes("Windows-1252"));
```

Comment: One perfect last line :)

Answer (score 1):

Now `String.getBytes()` uses the default encoding that may change on every platform.
You could use `getBytes(charset)`, but simpler is to use a Writer that does Strings instead of bytes.

The OutputStreamWriter can be given an encoding once, for all subsequent writes.

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(x) ;
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(file, true),
            "UTF-8")))) {
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        out.println(tokenizer.nextToken().toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

You might prefer `"Windows-1252"` for Windows Latin-1 or something else. UTF-8 has the advantage of being capable of combining all scripts, Cyrillic, Greek, Arabic.

Comment: since there is only an ability to choose one answer, I upvoted your nice answer instead.